# How to display value in JSbarcode

Tags: jquery, barcode

I'm using JSBarcode, I want to show HTML element value in bar-code dynamically, here is my code

In this, I want to show span value dynamically in JSBarcode:

```js
JsBarcode("#barcode2", "(span value should be here)", {
  format: "CODE128",
  displayValue: true,
  fontSize: 24,
  lineColor: "#666666"
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jsbarcode/3.6.0/JsBarcode.all.min.js"></script>
<img id="barcode2" />
<span id="awbno">9780199532179147</span>
```

Comment: replace `"(span value should be here)"` with `$("#awbno").text()`

Comment: its not working, check this fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/JonHome/fgbdx4pr/

Comment: Leonard look here https://jsfiddle.net/fgbdx4pr/5/ , you forgot to remove the `'` around `$("#awbno").text()` and your forgot to include jquery

Comment: I forgot to import jquery

It's working !! Thanks

Comment: @carsten-løvbo-andersen,
Could you pls check this fiddle again https://jsfiddle.net/JonHome/fgbdx4pr/17/

Comment: Here https://jsfiddle.net/fgbdx4pr/19/